# Работа рекурсивной функции, суть на машинном уровне

Tags: c++, c

```
void preOrderTravers(Node* root) {
if (root) {
    printf("%d ", root->data);
    preOrderTravers(root->left);
    preOrderTravers(root->right);
    }
}
```

Как работает рекурсия?
Вот допустим, что в обходе бинарного дерева мы вышли на левый нижний узел. Я так понимаю, формируются стек вызова рекурсивной функции, и, дойдя до тупика, машина переходит на предыдущий шаг и выполняет `preOrderTravers(root->right)`. Так, да? Просто я где то что то читал но не могу сейчас найти.

Comment: вызов рекурсивной функции, в общем случае, ничем не отличается от вызова обычной функции

Comment: Вы всегда можете взять IDA и посмотреть что получилось в итоге. Или можно посмотреть в отладчике самой студии.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Каждый вызов функции преобразуется в команду типа `call xxx`. В результате выполнения этой команды в стек заносится адрес возврата.
Пока не достигнуто дно рекурсии функция не завершается, а вызывает сама себя.
Когда достигается дно рекурсии функция завершается. При этом выполняется команда типа `ret`, которая выполняет переход по сохранённому в стеке адресу - происходит возврат на один уровень вверх.

Таким образом, в случае дерева, функция вызывает себя до достижения листа, что является признаком дна рекурсии. После этого происходит возврат из вызванных функций.

Comment: _в стек заносится возврата._ - что заносится?

Comment: адрес возврата.

Comment: @Grundy исправил, спасибо.